# Being $T(y)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{y-1}dx$ , $y\in(0,\infty)$ prove that $T\in C^{\infty}(0,\infty)$.

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Being $T(y)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{y-1}dx$ , $y\in(0,\infty)$ I have to prove that $T\in C^{\infty}(0,\infty)$.

---

There is a theorem that says the following:

Let we have the function $f:X\times I \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, being $f(\cdot,t) \in L_1 (X,\mu)$ for all $t\in I$. So the function $F(t)=\int_X f(x,t)d\mu(x)$, $t\in I$ satisfyes the followingstatements:

1. (A statement about continuity that I think I don't have to use).
2. If $f(x,\cdot)$ is derivable in $t_0$, for all $x\in X$ and $\exists g_2 \in L^1 (X,\mu)$, where $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)|\le g_2(x)$ for all $(x,t)\in x\times I$, $F$ is a derivable function in the point $t_0$ and $F'(t_0)=\int_X \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0) d\mu (x)$

So in my case, I've got a function $f:(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F(t)=\int_X f(x,t)d\mu(x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx$. So $f(x,t)=e^{-x}x^{t-1}$.

$f(x,\cdot)$ is derivable in $t_0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ and I have to see if there exists $g_2 \in L^1 (X,\mu)$ where $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)|=|x^{t-1}e^{-x}ln(x)|=\frac{x^{t-1}|ln(x)|}{e^x}\le g_2(x)$.

But I don't know how to bound $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)|$, I mean, I don't know how to choose that $g_2(x)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong. You can use the theorem and the fact that for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists $C_\varepsilon>0$ such that $\vert \ln(x)\vert \leq C_\varepsilon x^{-\varepsilon}$ for $x\in (0;1)$.

Comment: So which is my $g_2$?? I don't understand well what you say @SeverinSchraven

Comment: Ok, who is the enemy? It is the singularity at $x=0$. You want to take a derivative, you need to estimate $x^{t-1} \vert \ln(x) \vert e^{-x}$. Start with $t_0 \in (0;\infty)$. You only need to estimate $x^{t-1} \vert \ln(x) \vert e^{-x}$ for $t\in (t_0/2; 2t_0)$. Now pick $0<\varepsilon<t_0/2$, then we have $$ x^{t-1} \vert \ln(x) \vert e^{-x} \leq C_\varepsilon x^{t-1-\varepsilon}  e^{-x}. $$ Now, if $t-\varepsilon >0$, we get $t-1-\varepsilon>-1$, thus, we get that $x^{t-1} \vert \ln(x) \vert e^{-x}$ is in $L^1((0;\infty))$ and we are good to go.

Comment: So like that we reach to the conclusion that $T$ is derivative once, right? And now how can I prove that it is derivable infinity times? Do I have to apply the same process infinite times? @SeverinSchraven

Comment: Yes, you have to use induction. You will pick up powers of $\ln(x)$, but that does not change much in the argument.